# send file over blockchain

Tags: blockchain, p2p

I am wondering how can I send file over blockchain p2p network.

I know how to achive storing files in blockchain but I want to just send file from one client to another without saving it in a blockchain. I found some info about this here: http://troindia.in/journal/ijcesr/vol4iss4/169-175.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1kghQwT69uADRM0x4ggC_JhQZH-eJm4LDjqM6AUiUqrt5nshr5gNNTdqc

but without details how it is implemented in chain. 
Can someone explain how to send a file directly from client to client over blockchain without storing this file in chain?

EDIT: My goal is to file transfer between to clients in other private networks with the highest security level.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is specifically for **programming** questions. For broader questions regarding the blockchain, please ask on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead. For further information, please refer to the documentation regarding what is considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)' for StackOverflow, and what questions [**shouldn't be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload a file into blockchain, your file will be located on ALL computers, belong to appropriate network. And with this practice, when many users will be load entire file into blockchain - blockchain would be extremely and quick inflated. As result, cost of such network support will increased rapidly.

More realistic way - upload into blockchain some "anchor" for your file, when file will be stored our of a blockchain. For example you can upload an URL, or a torrent magnet link. Emercoin provide this service, see service prefix "magnet:" for NVS records.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a blockchain is applicable here. You only need a way to construct a secure channel between the clients to transfer the file over. Most encrypted P2P overlays provide a way to do this.